# ¿Por qué no puedo ingresar números complejos en mi programa de Gauss Jordan?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema con este programa que reduce matrices con el método de eliminación Gaussiana: solo funciona con números reales pero lo ocupo para trabajar con números complejos. Aquí les dejo el código que estoy utilizando y el error que me aparece al ingresar un número complejo.

```
import numpy as np

#Se pide el tamaño de la matriz, siendo m las filas y n las columnas

m=int(input('Valor de m:'))
n=int(input('Valor de n:'))

matrix = np.zeros((m,n))
vector = np.zeros((n))
x=np.zeros((m))

#El usuario ingresa la matriz de coeficientes y el vector solucion

print ('Introduce la matriz de coeficientes y el vector solución')

for r in range(0,m):
    for c in range(0,n):
        matrix[(r),(c)]=(input("Elemento a["+str(r+1)+","+str(c+1)+"] "))
    vector[(r)]=(input('b['+str(r+1)+']: '))
print(matrix)

for k in range (0,m):
    for r in range(k+1,m):
        factor=(matrix[r,k]/matrix[k,k])
        vector[r]=vector[r]-(factor*vector[k])
        for c in range(0,n):
            matrix[r,c]=matrix[r,c]-(factor*matrix[k,c])

#Resolucion de la matriz 

x[m-1]=vector[m-1]/matrix[m-1,m-1]
print (x[m-1])

for r in range(m-2,-1,-1):
    suma=0
    for c in range(0,n):
        suma=suma+matrix[r,c]*x[c]
    x[r]=(vector[r]-suma)/matrix[r,r]

#Se muestran los resultados de las tensiones de nodo

print ('Matriz ingresada')
print(matrix)
print ('Vector solución')
print(vector)
print ('Las tensiones de nodo son:')
print(x)
```

Este es el error cuando ingreso un número complejo.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-85a9a2150347> in <module>
     16 for r in range(0,m):
     17     for c in range(0,n):
---> 18         matrix[(r),(c)]=(input("Elemento a["+str(r+1)+","+str(c+1)+"] "))
     19     vector[(r)]=(input('b['+str(r+1)+']: '))
     20 print(matrix)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1+2j'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente

Comment: De nada! Cuando puedas marca la respuesta como válida ;)

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando `np.zeros` para crear la matriz y el vector vacíos, pero el tipo de datos por defecto para `np.zeros` es `(int)`. Cuando asignas el valor en `matrix[(r),(c)]=` intenta convertirlo a integer o a float y es donde genera la excepción. Simplemente tienes que crear las matrices con el `dtype` correcto.

```
matrix = np.zeros((m, n), dtype=complex)
vector = np.zeros(n, dtype=complex)
x = np.zeros(m, dtype=complex)
```

De esta manera al asignar el valor numpy convertirá los integer y floats a complejos.

Comment: También tiene que declarar de tipo complejo la matriz `x`, para evitar perder la parte imaginaria de los complejos al resolver

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Añadida la mejora de @abulafia